# what is that encoding ( \u041e\u0434\u0440 ) and how to I get it back to normal?

Tags: java, android, encoding

Say i have a string like that

```
"title": "\u041e\u0434\u0440\u0438\u043d\u044f-\u0423\u0440\u0431\u043e\u0432\u0430 ...
```

What would be the best way of getting it back to normal?

I tried

```
byte[] b = stringBuilder.toString().getBytes();
String jstring = new String(b,"UTF-8");
```

yet no luck, it stays the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are Unicode escape sequences. The quickest way to decode them (non-programmatically) is simply by pasting them into your browser's console, in quotes:

```
"\u041e\u0434\u0440\u0438\u043d\u044f-\u0423\u0440\u0431\u043e\u0432\u0430"
> "Одриня-Урбова"
```

There are a few answers here that show how to decode them in Java, for example:

- [unescape unicode from input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479728/unescape-unicode-from-input)
- [Reading unicode character in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630609/reading-unicode-character-in-java)
- [Java: How to create unicode from string "\u00C3" etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997325/java-how-to-create-unicode-from-string-u00c3-etc)

Answer (score 2):

That's not UTF-8 encoded, that's just a normal string. In Java, the `\uXXXX` is a Unicode character escape that represents the actual Unicode character at the given code point.

So, your string *is* normal, it's not encoded.

Comment: ok, but how do I turn it into a readable format in androud/java? :)

Comment: Just use it like you would any other string. Is something specific not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Did't try it, but [here](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/813/) you may find a helpful unicode escape string parser.

Answer (score 1):

The unicode characters will appear like áéíóú or something like that when you show them on the screen. I phased a similar situation parsing data with MySQL db using php so on the php file I encode the strange characters tu UTF-8, the a string like the one you have appeared, then when I presented the data on a list view the characters appeared as they should.

Answer (score 1):

It is already normal:

The following code

```
String str="\u041e\u0434\u0440\u0438\u043d\u044f-\u0423\u0440\u0431\u043e\u0432\u0430";    
System.out.println(str);
```

will print out: `Одриня-Урбова`

See the JLS-reference: [Unicode-Escapes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3)