# Hindi Character will not display in web view correctly

Tags: android, android-layout

I had Database in which data stored in hindi as `\u092e\u0948\u0902 \u0924\` and setting that content to webview using below.

```
  webview1.loadData(hindi_content, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

But it will display as

[image: hindi content display as]

I don't know why that's happening. Any one please suggest. how to fix that !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7395170/1168654

Comment: This question has already been answered. It's a duplicate.

Comment: The trick that mentioned over there is still not working. Could you please check the String that I am using for display Hindi text !! And could you please refer question again !

Comment: मैं त is this the sequence you are referring to?

Comment: It seems to me you have two problems. Unescaping that sequence into UTF-8 and then rendering it. The first problem you have is making sure you unescape this correctly which I'm guessing you're not doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because of a bug with the encoding parameter of `loadData` in most Android versions. This parameter is ignored for some reason so the UTF-8 based hindi characters will not be rendered.
To fix this you can use one of the following alternatives.

```
webview1.loadData(hindi_content, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);


webview1.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, hindi_content, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: Can you give a small sample of what hindi_content contains exactly (formatting and such)?

Comment: "\u092e\u0948\u0902 \u0924\" hindi words stored in DB. and it will looks like "आप".

Comment: Alright, and when you inspect the hindu_content variable during debugging (using a breakpoint/watch), it still contains that exact string?

Comment: \u092e\u0948\u0902 \u0924 is the correct sequence. No trailing backslash. This is two problems as I mentioned earlier. Correctly unescaping the sequence and the rendering it in a web view problem.

Comment: yeah its cause of I had put that as string but it's there without backslash. Still facing same issue.

Comment: @user1621629 I added to my answer a link for the unescaping in Java.

Answer (score 4):

This is a duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933069/android-webview-with-garbled-utf-8-characters/10831462#10831462):

You will also need to unescape those sequences and to do that refer to [How to Unescape Unicode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672363/what-is-that-encoding-u041e-u0434-u0440-and-how-to-i-get-it-back-to-normal/9672395#9672395)

Rendering UTF-8 in a WebView using loadData has been broken in some form or fashion forever.
[Issue 1733](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1733#c23)

Use loadDataWithBaseURL instead of loadData.

```
// Pretend this is an html document with those three characters
String scandinavianCharacters = "øæå";

// Won't render correctly
webView.loadData(scandinavianCharacters, "text/html", "UTF-8");

// Will render correctly
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, scandinavianCharacters, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Now the part that is truly annoying is that on the Samsung Galaxy S II (4.0.3) loadData() works just fine, but testing on the Galaxy Nexus (4.0.2) the multi-byte characters are garbled unless you use loadDataWithBaseURL(). [WebView Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

you will need to use font in order to support hindi (Hindi language is not yet fully supported by android)
create Singleton instance of **Typeface** and invoke createFromAsset();
and add it to WebSettings like this

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setFixedFontFamily(InstaceOFTypeFace);
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have come up with the solution of Loading hindi content to the webview.

I had simply change my loading string and unfortunately it will work.

```
webview.loadData(Hindi_css, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

Thank you all for your effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can  use this one also.

```
String uri= Uri.encode(html file/url);
  webView.loadUrl(uri);
```

may be this will help you.