# java - String hard code working but inputted not working

Tags: java, android

my problem is that if i use the String hardcode the answer is correct but if i use the inputed String not working .
for example :

```
 String variable = " \u0020\uFEB3\uFEE8\uFB93\u0020\uFEBB\uFE92\uFEEE\u0631\u0020";
 TextView show = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.preshow);
 show.settext(variable );
```

textview shows : صنگ صبور

but:

```
  File filematn = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"SingingStudio/"+songname+"/"+songname+"file.txt");
    //Read text from file
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filematn));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
    }
    String variable = text.toString();
    TextView show = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.preshow);
    show.settext(variable );
```

textview shows :  \u0020\uFEB3\uFEE8\uFB93\u0020\uFEBB\uFE92\uFEEE\u0631\u0020

how can i fix it . thank you

Comment: Parse it out and convert the Unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're reading in the file, the backslashes are being escaped with a preceding backslash. Getting around this is not as simple as it appears but is covered in this SO question: [How to replace \\u by \u in Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035891/how-to-replace-u-by-u-in-java-string)

Comment: What method did you use to remove the backslashes out of curiosity?

Comment: Pattern unicode = Pattern.compile("\\\\u(.{4})");
Matcher matcher = unicode.matcher("aaa\\u2022bbb\\u2014ccc");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    int code = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1), 16);
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, new String(Character.toChars(code)));
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);