# Convert Unicode to UTF-8

Tags: java, string, utf-8, converters

My question may already have been answered on StackoverFlow, but I can't find it.
My problem is simple: I request data via an API, and the data returned have unicode characters, for example:

```
"SpecialOffer":[{"title":"Offre Vente Priv\u00e9e 1 jour 2019 2020"}]
```

I need to convert the "\u00e9e" to "é". 
I cant't make a "replaceAll", because I cannot know all the characters that there will be in advance.

I try this :

```
byte[] utf8 = reponse.getBytes("UTF-8")
String string = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
```

But the string still has "\u00e9e"

Also this :

```
byte[] utf8 = reponse.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String string = new String(utf8, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Also tried this :

```
    string = string.replace("\\\\", "\\");
    byte[] utf8Bytes = null;
    String convertedString = null;
    utf8Bytes = string.getBytes("UTF8") -- Or StandardCharsets.UTF_8 OR UTF-8 OR UTF_8;
    convertedString = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF8") -- Or StandardCharsets.UTF_8 OR UTF-8 OR UTF_8;;
    System.out.println(convertedString); 
    return convertedString;
```

But it doesn't work either.

I tested other methods but I think I deleted everything like that didn't work so I can't show them to you here.

I am sure there is a very simple method, but I should not search with the right vocabulary on the internet. Can you help me please ?

I wish you a very good day, and thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `string.getBytes("UTF-8");` instead of `string.getBytes("UTF8");` should do the trick.

Comment: @Joel Thank you for your comment, I just tested just now, but doesn't work either... :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string with Unicode encoding to a string of letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters)

Comment: Okay, try to convert it to Unicode first - then convert it utf8

Comment: @jhamon Thank you for your comment. I had already tested this method and I find it difficult to adapt it for my case. In my case, my String can also contain numbers, "u", and there can be lots of unicodes distributed randomly.

Comment: There are multiple answers in the linked question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I had not seen, is that the API did not return me "\u00e9e" but "\\u00e9e" as it was a character sequence and not a unicode character!
So I have to recreate all the unicodes, and everything works fine!

```
int i=0, len=s.length();
        char c;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(len);
        while (i < len) {
            c = s.charAt(i++);
            if (c == '\\') {
                if (i < len) {
                    c = s.charAt(i++);
                    if (c == 'u') {
                        // TODO: check that 4 more chars exist and are all hex digits
                        c = (char) Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i+4), 16);
                        i += 4;
                    } // add other cases here as desired...
                }
            } // fall through: \ escapes itself, quotes any character but u
            sb.append(c);
        }
        return sb.toString();
```

Find this solution here: 
[Java: How to create unicode from string "\u00C3" etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997325/java-how-to-create-unicode-from-string-u00c3-etc)

Answer (score 0):

The String.getBytes method requires a valid Charset [1]

From the javadoc [2] the valid cases are

- US-ASCII
- ISO-8859-1
- UTF-8
- UTF-16BE
- UTF-16LE
- UTF-16

So you need to use UTF-8 in the getBytes method.

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.nio.charset.Charset-
[2] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

Comment: and by the way, UTF-8 is a particular way of encoding Unicode

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I modified my question, so I specified that I also tested with StandardCharsets.UTF_8 and "UTF-8", and it doesn't work either

Comment: You can also use Commons Lang library as reported in the question reported by @jhamon

Answer (score 0):

You can use small [json](https://github.com/antonsjava/json) library

```
String jsonstring = "{\"SpecialOffer\":[{\"title\":\"Offre Vente Priv\\u00e9e 1 jour 2019 2020\"}]}";
JsonValue json = JsonParser.parse(jsonstring);
String value = json.asObject()
    .first("SpecialOffer").asArray().get(0)
    .asObject().first("title").asStringLiteral().stringValue();
System.out.println(" result: " + value);
```

or

```
String text = "Offre Vente Priv\\u00e9e 1 jour 2019 2020";
System.out.println(" result: " + JsonEscaper.unescape(text));
```